# WPF - Declaring a custom routed event and listening to it

Tags: c#, wpf, events

In short: I want to declare a custom routed event and at the same time listen to it from the same user control that declared it.

What I want to achieve is to have a user control that serves requests for a certain task, so I imagined this scenario:

- the user control class declare a custom routed event
- the user control class listen to its own custom routed event through AddHandler(...)

Then:

- some random item in the visual tree use RaiseEvent(...) to...well, raise the event.
- an instance of the user control in the tree serves the request.

It doesn't seem to work. It's a bit different from the usual scenario where the user control declare and raise the event, I know, so I did some testing.

---

How to create a custom routed event seems clear, it's not the first time I do it. I have created an example user control, and this it's code behind:

```
public partial class FuffaControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly RoutedEvent FuffaEvent =  
        EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("Fuffa", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, 
           typeof(FuffaEventHandler), typeof(FuffaControl));

    // Provide CLR accessors for the event
    public event FuffaEventHandler Fuffa
    {
        add { AddHandler(FuffaEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(FuffaEvent, value); }
    }

    public FuffaControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

So far, so good. Then, for test purpose, I've declared a window with the custom control inside and a button. This is the content of the window:

```
<Grid>
    <local:FuffaControl>
        <Grid>
            <Button Content="Fuffa" Click="Button_Click"/>
         </Grid>
    </local:FuffaControl>
</Grid>
```

In the code behind, I use AddHandler to listen to the event and I raise the event on the click of the button:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.AddHandler(FuffaControl.FuffaEvent, new FuffaEventHandler(OnFuffaEvent));
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RoutedEventArgs newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(FuffaControl.FuffaEvent);
    RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
}

private void OnFuffaEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { }
```

It works. It makes not much sense (I mean, it's not that useful), but I'm using it just to test that the event itself works correctly. Ok, unless C# is doing something weird and cutting a few corners, but at a first glance it seems to me that the button is raising a custom event, the event travels up through the tree (it's a bubbling event, after all), and the window receives it.

So, next I take the AddHandler(...) call and the handler function and move them to the user control; now it's not the window who listen to the Raisevent(...), but the user control itself. If it works, I have children elements raising an event, and the parent user control managing it:

```
public partial class FuffaControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly RoutedEvent FuffaEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("Fuffa", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(FuffaEventHandler), typeof(FuffaControl));
    // Provide CLR accessors for the event
    public event FuffaEventHandler Fuffa
    {
        add { AddHandler(FuffaEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(FuffaEvent, value); }
    }

    public FuffaControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.AddHandler(FuffaControl.FuffaEvent, new FuffaEventHandler(OnFuffaEvent));
    }

    private void OnFuffaEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

---

Nnnnnope. It doesn't work. Why? What's wrong with this? Why the user control cannot listen to its own event?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason is in how you raise that event:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RoutedEventArgs newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(FuffaControl.FuffaEvent);
    RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
}
```

Routed event (like regular .NET event) has source (sender) and arguments. You only specify arguments, and sender is the control on which you call `RaiseEvent`. You do this from `MainWindow` class, so source of event will be MainWindow, not button (button does not participate in your event raising code at all as you may notice). WPF will search handlers for routing event starting from sender and then will go up or down hierarchy, depending on event type. In your case event is bubbling so it will search up the tree, starting from MainWindow. Your control is child of window so its handler will not be found.

Instead you should call `RaiseEvent` on button. Then button will be sender and it will work as you expect:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
   ((FrameworkElement) sender).RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(FuffaControl.FuffaEvent));
}
```

Comment: Someone kill me, please.

Comment: From that comment it's not clear if my answer helped or not :)

Comment: yes, helped: now I'm sure it's time to hang up the keyboard and change job.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance it seems you're implementing the `UserControl` as a `ContentControl` instead. Nevertheless you could get this to work by moving all the logic to the UC and calling a public `RaiseFuffaEvent` from the window's `Button_Click` handler.

**FuffaControl.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class FuffaControl : UserControl
{
    public FuffaControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AddHandler(FuffaEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnFuffaEvent));
    }

    public static readonly RoutedEvent FuffaEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
        "Fuffa", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(FuffaControl));

    public event RoutedEventHandler Fuffa
    {
        add { AddHandler(FuffaEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(FuffaEvent, value); }
    }

    public void RaiseFuffaEvent()
    {
        RoutedEventArgs newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(FuffaEvent);
        RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
    }

    private void OnFuffaEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

With this implementation of `RaiseFuffaEvent`, other controls can still listen for the event, even though it's raised from the window's code behind.

**Window.xaml**

```
<Window 
    ...>
    <Grid>
        <local:FuffaControl x:Name="fuffa">
            <Button Content="Fuffa" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="Button_Click"/>
        </local:FuffaControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Window.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        fuffa.RaiseFuffaEvent();
    }
}
```

For completeness, in a "normal" `UserControl` you would place the button in `FuffaControl.xaml` and set up the `Button_Click` handler in `FuffaControl.xaml.cs`.

Comment: But in your `RaiseFuffaEvent` you just call `OnFuffaEvent` directly, bypassing whole event system.

Comment: @Evk Point taken, updated my code. Still, your solution is way better.

Comment: @Funk your solution is ok, but it somehow defeat what I'm trying to achieve. I'm basically trying to build a "service provider" which resides in the visual tree (and even multiple instances of it) and that is transparent to everyone: simply a user control forward a request and the nearest "service provider" will satisfy it, but nobody knows anything about each other position or even existence. But thx for the help anyway :-)